# Mismatched input 'to' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Tags: pine-script

```
compareFunction(start, len) =>
    for i = start to len
        if not long
            if x[1] < x[i]
            false
        else
            if x[1] > x[i]
            false
    true
```

where is the problem, I can't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `false` statements under your `if` statements are not properly indented.

It should be like this:

```
compareFunction(_start, _len) =>
    for i = _start to _len
        if not long
            if x[1] < x[i]
                false
        else
            if x[1] > x[i]
                false
    true
```